# Why do i only get the first input exported to .txt file and not all inputs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, export

I have tried multiple ways to do this but I struggle. I am new to Python trying to learn currently.

```
CustomerList = []
    Customers = {}
    Dates = {}
    while True:
        Customer_Name = input("Customer's Name:")
        CustomerList.append(Customer_Name)
        Customers_Address = input("Customer's Address:")
        if Customer_Name in Customers:
            Customers[Customer_Name]['Orders'] += 1
            Customers[Customer_Name]['TotalAmount'] = Total_Amount
    

        else:
            Customers[Customer_Name] = {}
            Customers[Customer_Name]['Address'] = Customers_Address
            Customers[Customer_Name]['Orders'] = 1
            Customers[Customer_Name]['TotalAmount'] = 0
        file1 = open('Orders_Per_Users.txt', 'w')
        file1.write(Customer_Name + " has ordered " + str(Customers[Customer_Name]['Orders']) + " times in total\n")
        file1.close()
```

This is the output[image]

And this is what I get exported from this output [image]

What I want  to .txt export for example is.

```
John has ordered 1 times in total
Mike has ordered 1 times in total
etc
etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your file permission should be append

w -

> Opens in write-only mode. The pointer is placed at the beginning of
> the file and this will overwrite any existing file with the same name.
> It will create a new file if one with the same name doesn't exist

a -

> Opens a file for appending new information to it. The pointer is
> placed at the end of the file. A new file is created if one with the
> same name doesn't exist. .

```
file1 = open('Orders_Per_Users.txt', 'a')
```

Answer (score 2):

Opening with a 'w' tag means you are opening the file in write mode. write mode overwrites the previously existing text if any or creates a new file if the file doesnt exist.So what you might wanna do is opening it in 'a' mode (append mode) so that it doesnt overwrite the file but just appends text to it

```
file1 = open('Orders_Per_Users.txt', 'a')
file1.write(Customer_Name + " has ordered " + str(Customers[Customer_Name]['Orders']) + " 
times in total\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope you're enjoying your learning :)

problems are:

- your code just update the text each time you add an item because of the mode of write/read operation of the file, you coded it like this:

  file1 = open('Orders_Per_Users.txt', 'w')
  While the correct mode is `'a'` instead of `'w'` to append to the file without erasing old written text!
- **NOTE**: even if you correct it to be `'a'` another issue will appear! the line will be written again in entering new order!

*So what you should do is closing the file `file1.close()` each time you write to it in the while so your code will be looks like this:*

```
CustomerList = []
Customers = {}
Dates = {}
while True:
    Customer_Name = input("Customer's Name:")
    CustomerList.append(Customer_Name)
    Customers_Address = input("Customer's Address:")
    if Customer_Name in Customers:
        Customers[Customer_Name]['Orders'] += 1
        Customers[Customer_Name]['TotalAmount'] = Total_Amount


    else:
        Customers[Customer_Name] = {}
        Customers[Customer_Name]['Address'] = Customers_Address
        Customers[Customer_Name]['Orders'] = 1
        Customers[Customer_Name]['TotalAmount'] = 0
    file1 = open('Orders_Per_Users.txt', 'a')
    file1.write(Customer_Name + " has ordered " + str(Customers[Customer_Name]['Orders']) + " times in total\n")
    file1.close()
```